# How to create a segmented control and read values from SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var favoriteColor = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $favoriteColor, label: Text("What is your favorite color?")) {
                Text("Red").tag(0)
                Text("Green").tag(1)
                Text("Blue").tag(2)
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

            Text("Value: \(favoriteColor)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And where is a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already nearly there!

First, you make a variable called `favoriteColor`. You intend to use this variable to get the value from the Picker, aren't you?

Then, you pass that variable to the Picker. Not just as a variable, but as a Binding, with the `$` sign in front of it. This will make sure that your variable always stays in sync with the Picker. Briefly said, what Binding does, is that there's actually only one variable, which is shared by your View and the Picker. If you want to know more about this, I believe that there are hundreds of tutorials on this on the internet, so it would not really make sense if I would explain it here yet another time!

So what will happen, is that the Picker updates your variable when a selection is made. *But what value will it give your variable for which option?*

Well, that's the value you specified in those `.tag(...)`s. So when the user selects "Red", favoriteColor gets a value of 0, for "Green" it gets 1, for "Blue" it gets 2.

What about updating the UI when the selection changes? Well, SwiftUI manages this automatically -- this is one of the best things of SwiftUI!

But one more thing. When you use the value in a `Text` like you are doing, you will see something like "Value: 1" at runtime. It would be nice if we could display the name of the color, isn't it?

There's a lot of ways to do this, but one would be to replace `Text("Value: \(favoriteColor)")` with:

```swift
Text("Favorite Color: \(["Red", "Green, "Blue"][favoriteColor])")
```

What this does, is that it creates an array and takes the value out of it that corresponds with the index of the selected color. So when favoriteColor is 0, the first element of the array is taken , which is "Red".

Hope this is helpful for you!!